# tikz - use relative coordinate with control command

Tags: tikz-pgf

To translate svg command to tikz, I try below two case which should be output the same curve. Per svg spec, C means absolute coordinate and c means relative coordinate.

Below two svg command should mean the same shape:

```
M145,399 C219,75 371,92 460,323
M145,399 c74,-324 226,-307 315,-76
```

I try to use below tikz code to generate the same path but looks like my understand is wrong!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1,y=0.1]
    %M145,399 C219,75 371,92 460,323 
    \draw [yscale=-1] (145,399) .. controls (219,75) and (371,92) .. (460,323);
    %M145,399 c74,-324 226,-307 315,-76
    \draw [yscale=-1,red] (145,399) .. controls +(74,-324) and +(226,-307) .. +(315,-76); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't very obvious, but it's documented in section 13.4.1 *Specifying relative coordinates* of the TikZ manual (for version 3.1.8b). I quote:

> There is a special situation, where relative coordinates are interpreted differently. If you use a relative
> coordinate as a control point of a Bézier curve, the following rule applies: First, a relative first control point
> is taken relative to the beginning of the curve. **Second, a relative second control point is taken relative to
> the end of the curve.** Third, a relative end point of a curve is taken relative to the start of the curve.

Emphasis mine. That means your second relative control point has to be `(371-460, 92-323) = (-89,-231)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1,y=0.1]
    \draw [yscale=-1, very thick] (145,399) .. controls (219,75) and (371,92) .. (460,323);
    \draw [yscale=-1,red, dashed] (145,399) .. controls +(74,-324) and +(-89,-231) .. +(315,-76); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apropos SVG, if you add `\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}` you can do e.g. `\draw [very thick] svg[scale=0.1, yscale=-1] {M145,399 C219,75 371,92 460,323};`